# How to create vertical addition using the Word '13 equation editor

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I wish to recreate the following vertical addition using the equation editor in Microsoft Word 2013:

[image: ab+bb=bca as a vertical addition]

I have tried using an empty 3x3 matrix and filling it with the relevant symbols, however I cannot draw the horizontal line in-between the problem and the solution.

[image: vertical addition without the horizontal line]

I have also tried using separate equations and an underbar accent. However this is a less-than-ideal solution due to the space characters used for horizontal spacing. <sup><sub>(*shudder*)</sub></sup>

[image: vertical addition using underbars and spaces]

**Is there a way I can elegantly reproduce vertical addition using the MS Word 2013 equation editor?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changed this a little, as I'd missed the horizontal line).

Create a new equation, then copy/paste the following:

```
\matrix(+&\matrix(a&b@c&d))/\matrix(b&c&a)
```

and press Enter at the end.

The \matrix keywords will transform into \'square black blob character" at some point each "&" introduces a new column, and each "@" introduces a new row). Math autocorrect needs to be "on" to make it work - it should be "on" by default.

It should look like this:

[image]

For more space over the line, you can insert a blank line in the upper matrix, like this:

```
\matrix(+&\matrix(a&b@c&d)@ & )/\matrix(b&c&a)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to write columnar additions and it gives a similar look to what you presented above.

1. Add a blank equation (Ribbon: `Insert` > `Equation`).
2. From the `Equation Tools` tab in the Ribbon, add a `Stacked fraction` in button `Fraction`.

**If you prefer to centre the plus sign like in this picture**

[image]

3. Place the cursor on the blank square on the numerator and insert a `1x2 empty matrix` from button `Matrix`. You will get 2 blank squares on the numerator.
4. Place the cursor on the right blank square on the numerator and insert a `2x2 empty matrix` from button `Matrix`. You will get 4 more blank squares. **Go to instruction 6.**

**If you prefer to place the plus sign like in this picture**

[image]

5. Place the cursor on the blank square on the numerator and insert a `2x3 empty matrix` from button `Matrix`.
6. Place the cursor on the denominator and insert a `1x3 empty matrix` from button `Matrix`.

   - Finally, type in the characters on each blank square in the matrices.

**Pros**

- This is a one-block equation that moves all-together, not 2 equations separated by underscore characters.

**Cons**

- Not that different from what you demonstrated in your question, at least to me.

Comment: @angussidney I edited my answer to match your desired look, although I'm sure the plus sign is never centred in vertical addition. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition or google images for 'columnar addition' and see how the mark is normally placed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is much easier and nicer to use matrices, but if you are looking to add a horizontal line in Word (in general, to separate equations), you can utilize the fraction bar.

[image: sample horizontal line use case]

Create an empty fraction using (/) and in the top, keep on pressing control-tab until you obtain the necessary horizontal line length (you can press space to fine-tune your line length). Finally, select the bottom of the fraction, press space one time, and voila[image: gif of fractional bar]

[image: final completed vertical bar]

Answer (score 0):

I just put my vertical equation into Excel, making the columns appropriately sized for my numbers.  Formatting the cells as text allowed me to put in a plus sign without having it be interpreted as a formula.  I left off the bottom line.  When I copied these cells and pasted them into my word document, it created columns and everything is still lined up correctly.  I then inserted a shape (line) to provide the bottom line.